# How can I call the method with parameters as an annotation

Tags: java, annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a method be called passive before invoke a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163908/how-to-make-a-method-be-called-passive-before-invoke-a-method)

for example:

```
public class Robot{
    public static void doSomethingBefore(){
        System.out.println("Do something before sayHello");
    }
}

public class Person {
    @MethodListener(className="Robot",methodName="doSomethingBefore")
    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Person().sayHello();
    }
}
```

If I do like this using the annotation :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface MethodListener {
    public String className();
    public String methodName();
}
```

the output will be:

Do something before sayHello
hello

now if I want to make some changes in doSomethingBefore method :

```
public class Robot{
    public static void doSomethingBefore(String name){
        System.out.println("Do something before sayHello "+name);
    }
}
```

how should the Annotation definition look like i. e. what changes are needed in MethodListener Annotation?
Please let me know... 
Thanks in advance

Comment: not quite clear what you want

Comment: Possible duplicate? Definite duplicate! Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is strictly connected with this question [How to make a method be called passive before invoke a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163908/how-to-make-a-method-be-called-passive-before-invoke-a-method) Even sample code is the same. Please read those answers first (it will explain you some things) and then add more specific question.